# WP-CLI wp theme install url PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

Tags: themes, installation, wp-cli

I tried use wp-cli theme install with option url from my dropbox link. But unfortunately, I got this problem:

PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature

This mean my zip file is corrupt. But I tried upload it through wordpress dashboard and it's work good. I tried again with free theme in wordpress.org/themes and it's work good too, so maybe the problem in my vps setting?

Maybe someone meet this problem, has resolved it and help me sort it out?

Reference: http://wp-cli.org/commands/theme/install/

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with dropbox link. The zip file work good with other storage service, but seems the google drive similar error.

In my case, it's work good with cloudup storage service.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following storage sites:

`onedrive            failed
mega.co.nz          failed
dropbox             failed**`

dropbox works if you change the end of the link as below

`wp theme install https://www.dropbox.com/.../filename.zip?dl=0`

to

`wp theme install https://www.dropbox.com/.../filename.zip?dl=1`

note the 1 on the end. now works.